# Why do AutoRest generate my client with name UnknownType

Tags: c#, autorest

The swagger file I am trying to generate a c# client for is at:
https://gist.github.com/s093294/a98d53c961e40b0fa3d8

but for some reason, even though it has the info.title set, the  generted client is named Unknowntype

```
public partial class Unknowntype : ServiceClient<Unknowntype>, IUnknowntype
{

}
```

Anyone who can explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i downloaded the file from github and put it into my project and used autorest from visual studio against the local file, the problem was solved.

Not sure if the file got cached somewhere when using the url to github.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to rename the Client Namespace in the "Add REST API Client" dialog that comes up. When I left it as is, the problem went away for me.